# Anonymous functions in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, anonymous-function, c#-to-vb.net

The following syntax is valid VB.NET code

```
Dim myCollection As New List(Of Stock)
myCollection.Add(New Stock(Guid.NewGuid, "Item1"))
myCollection.Add(New Stock(Guid.NewGuid, "Item2"))

Dim res As List(Of Stock) = myCollection.FindAll(Function(stock As Stock) As Boolean
                                                     If stock.Description = "Item2" Then
                                                         Return True
                                                     End If
                                                     Return False
                                                 End Function)
```

How can I accomplish the same thing in C#? I have tried...

```
myCollection.FindAll(bool delegate(Stock stock) {
                        if (blah blah) {
                        }
                     });
```

But it appears I have somehow structured it incorrectly as I get the following error. "Error    1   Invalid expression term 'bool'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `bool` keyword. The return type is determined automatically based on the code in the anonymous function. Also, look into C# lambda expressions - it's a short-form of the same thing, and can be more clear than the traditional anonymous method.

Example of lambda usage:

```
myCollection.FindAll(stock => stock.Description == "Item2");
```

Comment: And from the delegate type it's being converted to.

Comment: Forgetting lambda usage for a moment (which I will admit looks like an incredibly elegant solution). Is there anyway that I can explicitly specify the return type as I only do it for clarity. PS: Is similar syntax possible in VB.NET?

Comment: PS: Not that its a big deal but I just noticed I think you are doing an assignment instead of a comparison in your example code.

Comment: @Maxim - If you want better readability then a better approach would be to assign the delegate to a variable and pass that in instead e.g. `myCollection.FindAll(DescriptionEquals("Item2"))`

Comment: @maxim the equivalent syntax in VB is myCollection.FindAll(Function(stock) stock.Description = "Item2")

Comment: @ MarkJ Thank you. I was not aware such syntax existed in VB.NET

Answer (score 4):

The following would be the equivalent C# code using a lambda expression

```
myCollection.FindAll((stock) => stock.Description == "Item2");
```

Using an anonymous function the above would be writen as follows

```
myCollection.FindAll(delegate(Stock stock) 
                     {
                       return stock.Description == "Item2";
                     });
```

You do not specify the return type for the anonymous function as you do in VB.NET

Comment: You don't need it in VB.Net either, at least if you turn on 'Option Infer'

Comment: Yeah but I consider not specifying a return type as code smell. Especially in a language like VB, which allows you to get away with so much.

Comment: @Maxim Most people recommend you turn on `Option Strict` in VB. Then it doesn't let you get away with anything - makes it more similar to C# in that respect.

Answer (score 2):

It could be converted to a lambda expression.

```
myCollection.FindAll(s => s.Description == "Item2");
```